# How can I fix this error while opening jupyter notebook from powershell?

Tags: python, windows, powershell

I'm getting this error from windows powershell when I write jupyter notebook. I'm able to open jupyter notebook from anaconda but not able to open from windows powershell. How can I fix this?

jupyter : The term 'jupyter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- jupyter notebook
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (jupyter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the Anadonda version of the `jupyter` commands working properly from PowerShell you should activate the conda environment (basically the same thing the Anaconda PowerShell Prompt does). I recommend that you add the conda activation process to your PowerShell Profile.

To do this you open your profile from PowerShell environment with `notepad $profile`

Add the following line to your profile:

```
& 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3'
```

Save your profile and close and re-open PowerShell and you should now be able to use `jupyter`.

Comment: Thank you for help. I never thought from Anaconda Powershell Prompt, so I just linked it with normal Powershell and it worked.